# Zend_Session::start() in bootstrap

Tags: zend-framework

can you tell me how to include the Zend_Session::start() in a bootstrap file of zf app?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the application resource - http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html#zend.application.available-resources.session

All you need to do is provide a "session" section in your config file "resources" section.

At a minimum, I'd recommend setting a session name, eg

```
resources.session.name = "MyAppName"
```

or if using Zend_Config_Xml

```
<resources>
    <session>
        <name>MyAppName</name>
    </session>
</resources>
```

If you want to do some session stuff in your Bootstrap class, just make sure you bootstrap the session resource first to pick up your configuration options, eg

```
protected function _initSessionNamespaces()
{
    $this->bootstrap('session');

    // now create your namespace(s) and whatnot
}
```

Comment: is this equivalent to the adding the Zend_Session::start() in bootstrap though ?, so that I can just create a new namespace and iterate over it..( noob here ) ....what's that in your example ?..is "MyAppName" the namespace ? , what if I want many namespaces ?

Comment: No, it's the session name (the name given to the session cookie). See here for config options - http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.session.global_session_management.html. Zend_Session::start() is automatically called when you instantiate the first Zend_Session_Namespace so you don't really need to worry about it.

Comment: ok let me verify, you mean, I'll add that resources.session.name = "MyAppnName" first in the "application.ini" file of my app and then do that _iniSession at the Boostrap.php ?

Comment: Yes, something like that though I'd refrain from using `_initSession` as this will override the default "session" application resource bootstrapping (I think).

Comment: there's no need to do that xml file then ?..i got confused now lol, someone said, it's automatically started ? http://i56.tinypic.com/2elbmzk.jpg    (btw am using 1.10.8 )

Comment: You should always set your session cookie name to avoid conflicts with other PHP applications on the same domain. The best place to do this is in your config

Comment: The session is started if you use "$session = new Zend_Session_Namespace();" But Phil is right, it is better practisce to provide an unique name

Comment: ok I added that thing cookie name in Phil's example. then I created a name space like this $sess = new Zend_Session_Namespace('userNamespace'); in one of my controllers  .. set the value as $sess->username = $q->WSloginName; ...now I called it in the view file as echo $sess->username ..i got a foreach error when am not even using a foreach loop..why is that ?

Comment: @ArneRie The two are mutually exclusive. The config setting should just come first.
@sasori What does the error say? They (error messages) usually tell you where the error occurred.

Comment: Your session will persist across requests however your view members will not. When you redirect, are you setting the `username` view member again in the MemberController::profileAction()? The error may be triggered by the `__get` magic method of Zend_View though I've not seen it crop up like that before.

Comment: @Phil actually the member is a module name, the controller is Profile and the action in the Profile is index alone..so it's  Member_ProfileController::indexAction() ,, can you give me an idea how can I retrieve the session value that I set from the AccountController after redirecting ?, because I tested a fresh install a ZF app and tweaked nothing, then I tried the session in a default indexcontroller and index view it is working.. but in my app, i dunnno what's going on

Comment: Simple. In `Member_ProfileController::indexAction()`, instantiate a session namespace (`$sess`) and assign `$sess->username` to `$view->username`